# OpenApi generator generating empty lines between annotations

Tags: java, spring, openapi, openapi-generator

```
  /**
   * Get form
   * @return form
  */
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")

  @Valid

  public AlertForm getForm() {
    return form;
  }
```

or

```
  /**
   * Get data
   * @return data
  */
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")


  public Object getData() {
    return data;
  }
```

Any idea how to get rid of that? I'm using plugin version 5.0.0. Here's the configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${openapitools.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>client-api</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/api/client-api.yaml</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <apiPackage>com.org</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>com.org.model</modelPackage>
                <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiUtil.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>
                <configOptions>
                    <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                    <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                    <dateLibrary>java8-localdatetime</dateLibrary>
                    <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                </configOptions>
                <ignoreFileOverride>
                    ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/.openapi-generator-ignore
                </ignoreFileOverride>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I cannot find any useful information and I'm pretty new to open api generation so I'd be grateful for any leads.

Answer (score -1):

You can use your favourite code formatter/linter (e.g. [prettier.io](https://prettier.io/)) to massage the auto-generated code based on your preferred code style.

Comment: Not really sure that's an option, since the classes will be generated with every package build and so the format will be lost. I just want them to be more readable.